# Including additional variable, the variable of interest becomes insignificant

Tags: r, regression, stata

I am examining BMI effect on wage. I have included a lot of explanatory variables in the regression and all (most) coefficients were significant, but once I add ability which correlates with education (already in regression) slightly (34%) BMI measures turn insignificant.

Here is the question, what does it mean if BMI turns insignificant once we add another variable in the regression?

Estimated by OLS, cross sectional. Adj R  0.60, F=160.

PS: I added a variable and variable of interest turned insignificant, not vice versa. 
Thank you for all the examples below, they address the same topic, but different issue.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This question has been asked before: for more see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27257/), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34488/), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116804/), & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78828/).

Comment: A variable turning insignificant is not the primary focus of the main linked thread, but is a FAQ, & is covered in several of the other threads @Scortchi helpfully listed for you. You may want to spend some time searching & reading on the site.