# Changed signs from correlation to unique effect

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, fixed-effects-model

I am running a fixed effects regression and I found that one of the significant independent variables has a substantial positive correlation with the dependent variable but a negative unique effect in the regression results.

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Josh

Comment: Also see some very good answers [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27257/), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34488/), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116804/), & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78828/).