# manipulated IV becomes non-significant in mediation analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, mediation

When I use Baron & Kenny's approach to test mediation, I receive the following results (IV: independent variable, M: mediator, DV: dependent variable):

`DV ~ IV` : IV is significant

`M ~ IV` : IV is significant

`DV ~ IV + M` : M is significant, but IV not

Now, the curious thing is that these data are based on an experiment where I manipulated the independent variable IV, but not the mediator M (M measures perceptions of a person who acted differently depending on condition IV). Hence, theoretically, it seems implausible that in the multiple regression M is significant, but IV not. My question then is: what is going on here?

I believe that this question is different from related questions in that I provide information that IV is manipulated and M is not. I know from reading related questions (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142260/79643)) that two highly correlated variables may compete for variance. Yet it seems strange that a variable that has no causal relation (as it was not manipulated) "wins" this competition for variance over a variable that might have causal influence (as it was manipulated; the two variables IV and M are correlated .58).

**Update:** I typically use Preacher and Hayes' approach (in which case the mediation analysis is significant). Does this mean that Baron & Kenny's approach is not suited in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what you are looking for: After controlling for the mediator, the IV is no longer significant. This, according to the theory of mediation analysis, is because `M` is what accounts for the effect of the `IV` on the `DV`. Remember that manipulation is a methodological aspect; the statistical model does not know whether or not you manipulated something.

Let's say I assign people to drink (a) a rum and Coke or (b) water (`IV`), measure their blood alcohol content (`M`), and then see how well they do on a reaction task (`DV`).

If you ran a mediation model with this, drinking alcohol (`IV`) would no longer have an effect on the reaction task (`DV`) after controlling for blood alcohol content (`M`). This is exactly what we are looking for: The major shrinkage of the effect of the `IV` on the `DV` after controlling for the `M` shows that the `M` accounts for a lot of the effect of the `IV` on the `DV`.

Now, there are a lot of really good criticisms of mediation analysis and how this might not be justified, but according to the canon of mediation analysis, this is what you would expect; I don't see a problem in the `IV` no longer having an effect—to the contrary, it is what most researchers look for.

As for B&K vs. P&H, never use B&K. The Baron and Kenny approach assumes that the indirect effect (a path times the b path) is normally distributed, but products of coefficients are not normally distributed. This is why we use bootstrapping instead (e.g., P&H).

Comment: I think I was staring at my screen for too long, of course this is what mediation is about. Thanks for your friendly clarification!