# Multivariate logistic regression not returning expected significant p-values in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, multicollinearity

I am very new to R and statistics in general and have been stuck on this for a couple of weeks so any input would be greatly appreciated.

I have a binary outcome variable `TOTHLOS` and 14 categorical predictor variables. I am looking to run a multivariate logistic regression analysis to see which predictors are independently significant for my outcome variable. All predictor variables were screened with a `chisq.test` and binomial logistic regression and all were significant at that level. All predictors are categorical variables and have been set to factors.

As you can see, many of my predictor p-values become non-significant when all 14 are used. When predictor variables `ASA`, `OPTIME`, `PRHCT` and `PRSODM` are removed, I get a result a bit closer to what I was intuitively expecting.

I followed with a multicollinearity test, and nothing stood out to me.
I'd prefer to use all of my available predictors if possible, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the results I'm getting.

Any recommendations for how to overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
> a<-glm(TOTHLOS ~ age + SEX + relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White") + 
+        + relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA") + OPTIME + WNDCLAS+ relevel(PRSODM, ref = "upper")
+         + allq$SMOKE + allq$HYPERMED + allq$WNDINF   
+        + relevel(DYSPNEA, ref = "No") + relevel(allq$DIABETES, ref = "NO") + ASACLAS + relevel(allq$PRHCT, ref = "more than 40%")
+        , family = binomial(link = logit), data = allq)
> summary(a)


Call:
glm(formula = TOTHLOS ~ age + SEX + relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White") + 
    +relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA") + OPTIME + WNDCLAS + 
    relevel(PRSODM, ref = "upper") + allq$SMOKE + allq$HYPERMED + 
    allq$WNDINF + relevel(DYSPNEA, ref = "No") + relevel(allq$DIABETES, 
    ref = "NO") + ASACLAS + relevel(allq$PRHCT, ref = "more than 40%"), 
    family = binomial(link = logit), data = allq)

                                                                    Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                                          0.00011 ***
age21-25                                                             0.74438    
age26-40                                                             0.46263    
age>40                                                               0.38121    
SEXmale                                                              0.34529    
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")American Indian or Alaska Native     0.62249    
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")Asian                                0.05637 .  
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")Black or African American            0.23644    
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander  0.73275    
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")Unknown                              0.50956    
relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA")1 2 3                       0.04169 *  
relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA")1 2 NA                      0.75835    
relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA")1 NA NA                     0.56602    
OPTIME120-270                                                        0.03419 *  
OPTIMEmore than 270                                                 1.11e-11 ***
WNDCLAS2-Clean/Contaminated                                          0.52663    
WNDCLAS3-Contaminated                                                0.84918    
WNDCLAS4-Dirty/Infected                                              0.82255    
relevel(PRSODM, ref = "upper")lower                                  0.10154    
allq$SMOKEYes                                                        0.99345    
allq$HYPERMEDYes                                                     0.26749    
allq$WNDINFYes                                                       0.37926    
relevel(DYSPNEA, ref = "No")MODERATE EXERTION                        0.76996    
relevel(allq$DIABETES, ref = "NO")INSULIN                            0.44470    
relevel(allq$DIABETES, ref = "NO")NON-INSULIN                        0.91492    
ASACLAS2-Mild Disturb                                                0.16185    
ASACLAS3-Severe Disturb                                             4.51e-06 ***
ASACLAS4-Life Threat                                                 0.08671 .  
relevel(allq$PRHCT, ref = "more than 40%")Less than 30%              0.33039    
relevel(allq$PRHCT, ref = "more than 40%")30-40%                     0.21663
```

```
> a<-glm(TOTHLOS ~ age + SEX + relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White") 
+        + relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA") +  WNDCLAS 
+         + allq$SMOKE + allq$HYPERMED + allq$WNDINF   
+        + relevel(DYSPNEA, ref = "No") + relevel(allq$DIABETES, ref = "NO") 
+         
+        , family = binomial(link = logit), data = allq)
> summary(a)

Call:
glm(formula = TOTHLOS ~ age + SEX + relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White") + 
    relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA") + WNDCLAS + allq$SMOKE + 
allq$HYPERMED + allq$WNDINF + relevel(DYSPNEA, ref = "No") + 
relevel(allq$DIABETES, ref = "NO"), family = binomial(link = logit), 
    data = allq)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0482  -0.7535  -0.5747   0.8175   2.3258  

Coefficients:
                                                                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                                         -1.12770    0.29659  -3.802 0.000143 ***
age21-25                                                            -0.24989    0.21445  -1.165 0.243913    
age26-40                                                            -0.19453    0.20410  -0.953 0.340550    
age>40                                                               0.76249    0.20238   3.768 0.000165 ***
SEXmale                                                              0.23176    0.13600   1.704 0.088359 .  
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")American Indian or Alaska Native    -0.03884    0.78676  -0.049 0.960628    
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")Asian                               -0.66830    0.30019  -2.226 0.025998 *  
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")Black or African American           -0.06473    0.25987  -0.249 0.803295    
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander  0.47777    0.81317   0.588 0.556837    
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")Unknown                             -0.09488    0.17697  -0.536 0.591878    
relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA")1 2 3                       1.60320    0.19818   8.090 5.99e-16 ***
relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA")1 2 NA                      0.69963    0.19148   3.654 0.000258 ***
relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA")1 NA NA                     0.14957    0.17411   0.859 0.390304    
WNDCLAS2-Clean/Contaminated                                         -0.58958    0.24428  -2.414 0.015797 *  
WNDCLAS3-Contaminated                                               -0.55435    0.52177  -1.062 0.288035    
WNDCLAS4-Dirty/Infected                                              0.35967    0.61662   0.583 0.559699    
allq$SMOKEYes                                                        0.23343    0.21361   1.093 0.274482    
allq$HYPERMEDYes                                                     0.27592    0.23216   1.188 0.234637    
allq$WNDINFYes                                                       1.23271    0.57907   2.129 0.033273 *  
relevel(DYSPNEA, ref = "No")MODERATE EXERTION                        1.71415    0.76200   2.250 0.024479 *  
relevel(allq$DIABETES, ref = "NO")INSULIN                            1.11035    0.69261   1.603 0.108903    
relevel(allq$DIABETES, ref = "NO")NON-INSULIN                        0.57316    0.44634   1.284 0.199096
```

```
> car::vif(a)
                                               GVIF Df GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
age                                        1.707034  3        1.093219
SEX                                        1.306244  1        1.142910
relevel(RACE_NEW, ref = "White")           1.410674  5        1.035006
relevel(OTHERCPT_group, ref = "NA NA NA")  1.394826  3        1.057028
WNDCLAS                                    1.392669  3        1.056756
allq$SMOKE                                 1.135153  1        1.065436
allq$HYPERMED                              1.495988  1        1.223106
allq$WNDINF                                1.122629  1        1.059542
relevel(DYSPNEA, ref = "No")               1.046603  1        1.023036
relevel(allq$DIABETES, ref = "NO")         1.448180  2        1.096998
relevel(PRSODM, ref = "upper")             1.204106  1        1.097318
ASACLAS                                    2.123131  3        1.133695
relevel(allq$PRHCT, ref = "more than 40%") 1.552441  2        1.116230
OPTIME                                     1.321785  2        1.072236
```

Comment: Welcome. Is your only concern a difference of significance *between* the two models? Also, in each run you’re forcing the referent of one variable, namely `OTHERCPT_group`, to be a level with obvious missingness (e.g., `ref = “NA NA NA”`). Why are you doing this?

Comment: @ThomasBilach thank you for the response. My concern is that my original protocol called for including all variables that were significant in my uni- and bivariate screening, but as shown in my first model, this leads to some odd results and I've found that I have to remove certain variables to make the model work(as seen in the second model).
I'm not sure why removing select variables restores more p-values to significance and what effect this is having on my reported results. Thank you for the heads up on ```OTHERCPT_group ``` I will make that adjustment. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. I was curious if that was leading to irregularities. Also, what do you mean when you say make the model “work” in this context?

Comment: @ThomasBilach In my original model, it appears that ```OPTIME``` and ```ASACLAS``` are very significant. But when they are removed in my second model, I see many more predictors become significant that I was previously expecting to be significant(such as age, wound infection, etc). I'd like to figure out how to retain these significant predictors when running my original model. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt I could offer one solution that will satisfy all your concerns. I would argue a large difference in results is due to either a possible misspecification or a loss of degrees of freedom. Issues regarding causation/correlation should be obvious in a multiple (logistic) regression context. In your setting, your regression is concerned with the relationship between a dependent variable(s) and the independent variable(s) of interest—controlling for all the other independent variables in the model (i.e., holding them *fixed*). Your initial focus on some variables was discovered, in large part, during your *bivariate* screening process. Once you include other predictors, it is not uncommon to observe a former association between $x$ and $y$ disappear, or even reverse. In the end, it all depends upon what questions you're trying to answer. I could probably write ad nauseam about correlational differences across models, but I probably couldn't do better than some of the top answers  [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27257/significant-predictors-become-non-significant-in-multiple-logistic-regression) or even [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116804/coefficient-changes-sign-when-adding-a-variable-in-logistic-regression).

I know your gut is telling you multicollinearity is present, but your variance inflation factors suggest otherwise. In sum, if you're looking for some rule of thumb to help explain some instability in your model coefficients, I doubt you will find it. Your sundry list of predictors should have been chosen on the basis of theory. You must think long and hard about why holding one or more variables *fixed* might obscure a potentially important causal mechanism.

---

I also worry you're doing too much data cleaning inside of the `glm()` function. For example, your liberal use of the `relevel()` function is okay if used once, but multiple calls seems likely to result in coding errors, not to mention it makes your output inscrutable. It also isn't clear why `OTHERCPT_group == "NA NA NA"` is your referent. It is also difficult to decipher what the other *levels* denote, at least to a third party not familiar with your study. Pre-processing your data should have been taken care of long before a model is run. Thus, I would reexamine your model coefficients once you fix some of these irregularities.